# Delete Envelope in created state

Tags: docusignapi

How can I delete a draft envelope using REST API? (status=created).  I want to be able to destroy the envelope as it needs changes to subject and email blurb which I have been told is not possible via REST API after the creation of the envelope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To Delete through the DocuSign Console:

You can delete an envelope from your Drafts folder by navigating to that folder, selecting the envelope(s) in question, and deleting through the UI.

To Delete through the DocuSign REST API:

This is not well documented at the moment but this can be accomplished by using the **MoveEnvelope()** call and moving it into your **Recycle Bin** folder.  The following page from the REST API guide describes the call you need make:

[DocuSign REST API Guide - Move Envelopes](http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Move%20Envelope.htm)

The details of the call are as follows:

URL:

```
/accounts/{accountId}/folders/{folderId}
```

Method:

```
PUT
```

Body:

```
{
  "envelopeIds": [
    "sample string 1",
    "sample string 2"
  ],
  "fromFolderId": "sample string 1"
}
```

As with all other calls, this can be formatted in JSON or XML.  If using XML request bodies, use the following:

```
<envelopeMoveRequest xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
  <envelopeIds xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <d2p1:string>sample string 1</d2p1:string>
    <d2p1:string>sample string 2</d2p1:string>
  </envelopeIds>
  <fromFolderId>sample string 1</fromFolderId>
</envelopeMoveRequest>
```

Comment: Ergin, I see you note that the `Body` is null, but isn't a body necessary to specify the envelope to be deleted? Also, you mention that it can be formatted in either JSON or XML; however, we have no way of formatting in XML without knowing the name of the root element.

Comment: Ray- great point.  I think even the docs I linked show an example body, although the example envelope ids list is not too clear.  I'll fix up my answer in a bit, thanks.